# Making a Dataset that emulates `ls -tlra`?

Tags: files-and-directories

When we `ls -tlra` in bash, we get filename information, size of files, date last modified, etc. Is there a way to create a Mathematica function which generates a Dataset of all of this information?

Some key functions here: `FileNames[]`, `FileDate[]`, `FileSize[]`. I'm not sure how to get information about file permissions, but that is less important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Build your own

Here I create a [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) of files, taking advantage of the `"Rules"` option for [`FileDate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileDate.html). You can add your own information relevant for files or directories in the respective sections after [`DirectoryQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectoryQ.html). Just as a playful example I added [`FileHash`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileHash.html) which may slows down things considerably.

```
lstlra[dir_] := Dataset[
  <|(* For all files and directories  *)
     "FileName" -> FileNameTake[#],
     "Type" -> FileType[#],
     FileDate[#, "Rules"],
     If[
      DirectoryQ[#],
      <|(* Directory only *)
       |>,
      <|(* Files only *)
       "FileSize" -> FileSize[#],
       "MD5-Hash" -> FileHash[#]
       |>
      ]
     |> & /@ FileNames[All, dir]
  ][SortBy["Modification"]]
```

[image]

---

### Using File Information

After the answer by @swish, was very nice to learn about [`Information`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html) applied to [`File`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/File.html). Here I just change the [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) to and [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) (using [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) `@@`) to allow you to put your own stuff. Unfortunately it has too much information, more than you possible need.

```
lstlra2[dir_] := Dataset[
  <|
     Association @@ Information[File[#]],
     If[
      DirectoryQ[#],
      <|(* Directory only *)
       |>,
      <|(* Files only *)
       "MD5-Hash" -> FileHash[#]
       |>
      ]
     |> & /@ FileNames[All, dir]
  ][SortBy["LastModificationDate"]]
```

---

### Minimal

```
lstlra3[d_]:=SortBy[Dataset[Information[File[#]][[1]]&/@FileNames[d]],"LastModificationDate"]
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the final results sorted by date modified (this is also the behavior of `ls -tlra` I believe).

Comment: @George I added a minimalistic version, and all version sort as requested. Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 12):

Try something like that

```
props = {"CreationDate", "UnixPermissionsString", "ByteCount"};
ls[dir_] := 
 Dataset@FileSystemMap[
   AssociationThread[props -> Information[File@#, props]] &, dir]
```

Comment: Nice one! (+1) Thanks for introducing me to `Information` applied to `File`.

Comment: It gives me this error `Information::nonopt: Options expected (instead of props) beyond position 1 in Information[File[/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/Executables/math],props]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.`

Comment: @Fortsaint I believe [Information](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html) was substantially updated in version 12.

Answer (score 3):

Why not interpreting the stdout of `ls` itself

```
ls`tlra@path_:=ReadString["!ls -tlra "<>path] //
               StringSplit /@ Rest@StringSplit[#,"\n"]& //
               StringRiffle /@ Append[TakeList[#,{1,1,1,1,1,3}],#~Drop~8]& /@ #& //
               AssociationThread[
                  {"Permissions" ,"ID","Owner","Group","Size","CreationDate","Name"}->#
               ]& /@ #& // Dataset
```

[image]

Comment: Because then this becomes a platform specific answer...